# Get y-m from y-m-d in date PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get only the month and year on this format (y-m) coming from y-m-d format of date. 
I am getting an error saying Call to a member function format() on a non-object.
 Am i doing it correctly? Thank you for your help with this.

```
 $current_date= '2017-04-03';
 $d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m",$current_date);
 $current_date = $d->format("Y-m");
 echo $current_date;
```

Comment: You should create $d using the format that you've actually got (`Y-m-d`), not from the format that you want

Comment: change to `$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$current_date);`

Comment: I update my code and still the same error

Comment: Its working here : https://eval.in/767470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error was I put the following code inside the for loop.
After moving the code outside the loop, the only thing I changed was the code from:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m",$current_date);
```

to:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$current_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
$current_date= '2017-04-03';
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d",$current_date);
$current_date = $d->format("Y-m");
echo $current_date;
```